# no matching function for call to ‘node::node()’

Tags: c++

I am creating and displaying an singly linked list.
However there is an error in the main function

no matching function for call to ‘node::node()’

Following is my code:

```
#include <iostream.h>
 using namespace std;
 class node
 {
  node *next,*start,*ptr;
  int data;

  public:

  node(int d)
  {
    data=d;
    next=NULL;
    start=NULL;
    ptr=NULL;
  }
    void create();
    void display();
```

};

```
void node::create()
{
int d;
char ch;
node *temp;
do
{
cout<<"Enter data";
cin>>d;
temp=new node(d);
if(start==NULL)
{
    start=temp;
}
else
{
    ptr=start;
    while(ptr->next!=NULL)
    {
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next=temp;
    temp->next=NULL;
}
cout<<"\nDo you want to enter more data?";
cin>>ch;
}while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');
}
void node::display()
{
ptr=start;
while(ptr->next!=NULL)
{
    cout<<"\n"<<ptr->data;
    ptr=ptr->next;
}
cout<<"\n"<<ptr->data;
}
int main()
{
node n;
int c;
char a;
do
{
cout<<"*****MENU*****";
cout<<"\n1.Create \n2.Display";
cout<<"\nEnter your choice";
cin>>c;
switch(c)
{
case 1:
n.create();
break;
case 2:
    n.display();
break;
default:
    cout<<"\nInvalid choice";
    break;
}
cout<<"\nDo you want to continue?";
cin>>a;
}while(a=='y'||a=='Y');
    return 0;
}
```

When I write the same program using a friend class of node, the program executes successfully.
Why do we need to use more than one class?

Answer (score 2):

For your class `node` you defined only one constructor, that accepts parameter type `int`, which means you can construct instances of this class with such parameter, what you do here:

```
temp=new node(d); // fine, you pass int d to construct node
```

but in `main()` you try to create instance of class `node` without any parameters:

```
int main()
{
    node n; // <---- problem
```

so either pass integer when you create `n` in `main()` or define another constructor without any parameters (aka default constructor) for class `node`.